# Customize link / URL syntax highlighting color in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, vscode-extensions

I am creating my own Visual Studio Code theme, and I want the links / URLs to have their own independent color in HTML and CSS.  From what I have read it seems that this was once accomplished with detected-link, but should now use linkForeground.  I have tried both in the theme.json file I created, but neither seems to work.  Does anyone know how to customize link / URL syntax highlighting color in Visual Studio Code .json file?

This is what I tried...

{
    "name": "goto-definition-link",
    "scope": "linkForeground",
    "settings": {
        "foreground": "#4B83CD"
    }
},

Here is one of the discussions that I am referencing above.

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/18378

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to this: using [syntax colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers#_syntax-highlighting-colors) to set the color of links in the  grammar and using [workbench colors](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers#_workbench-colors) to set the color of a clickable link when the user hovers over it.

To set the syntax colors of a link, you need to determine a unique [scope](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers#_textmate-theme-rules) for the links and write a TextMate colorization rule that uses this scope. For example, using the `Developer: Inspect TM Scope` command in VS Code, I can see the css `url()` links have a scope of `variable.parameter.url.css`, so my theme would be:

```
{
    "type": "dark",
    "tokenColors": [
        {
            "scope": [
                "variable.parameter.url.css",
            ],
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#f0f"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The second one is easier; just use the  `editorLink.activeForeground` color theme setting:

```
{
    "type": "dark",
    "colors": {
        "editorLink.activeForeground": "#ff0",
        ...
    },
    "tokenColors": [ ... ]
}
```

This changes the color of the link when you hover over it. It cannot be changed per language.

[image]