# How do you change the colour of links in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a theme installed on VS Code that I really like but the color it uses for links is really hard to read.

[image: VS Code links]

Is there a way to customise the color of these links? I don't want to throw out the entire theme just because of this one issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Customize link / URL syntax highlighting color in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220878/customize-link-url-syntax-highlighting-color-in-visual-studio-code)

Comment: No it's not a duplicate, that is for specifying the color of url paths inside the code editor, this is for specifying the colour of actual links in things like markdown previews and on the welcome screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```json
"textLink.foreground": "#e06c75",
"textLink.activeForeground": "#41a6d9"
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference#_text-colors