# How can I customize the color of URLs in HTML text nodes in VS Code?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I have been unable to update the color or URLs in text and/or HTML files since starting to use VS Code (see screenshot). I've watched all the videos and nothing works. This option was a piece of cake on Atom, but for VS Code, it's impossible. Please help, the 'Inspect Editor Token and Scopes' does not work for line 82 in the screenshot.

Attempted solutions that didn't work:

1. https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#text-colors
2. [Customize link / URL syntax highlighting color in Visual Studio Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220878/customize-link-url-syntax-highlighting-color-in-visual-studio-code)
3. https://www.hmablogs.com/change-color-of-text-and-syntax-in-vscode-editor/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the builtin HTML language support of VS Code, you can't customize the colour of URL-like strings in text nodes in HTML.

If you inspect the TextMate scopes of such a token using `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` command in the command palette, all you'll see is `text.html.derivative`, which is the general scope for all text node text.

The reason that the URL-like string in the HTML text node is underlined is because VS Code just underlines URL-like strings as a general feature. See [the docs for `DocumentLinkProvider<T>`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentLinkProvider%3CT%3E), which state:

> Provide links for the given document. Note that the editor ships with a default provider that detects `http(s)` and `file` links.

All you can do is find or create a language extension that does provide a specialized TextMate scope for URL-like strings in text nodes in HTML, and then use that scope for customizing the colour. You can find the builtin HTML TextMate syntax definitions here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/html/syntaxes.